# Laravel updating a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my system `users` can have many `timesheets`, timesheets can have many data.

I'm trying to update the data rows in the `data_timesheet` table.  I'm using this:

```
$data = ['column_1' => 'value'];

$this->findTimesheetById($id)->data()->saveMany($data);
```

However, it's giving me the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given
```

I know why it's giving me the error, because I need to send it a model as opposed to an array.  **How can I send in a model, when the values being passed are from a user form?**

**EDIT:**

I can do this which works, but there must be a better way?

```
$data = $this->findTimesheetById($id)->data();
$data->delete();
$data->insert($data);
```

Comment: remove this part `->data()`

Comment: Is `data_timesheet` a pivot table, looks like a `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: No it's not a pivot table.  As I said above, a timesheet can have many data but each data row only belongs to one timesheet.

Answer (score -1):

The way to do that is:

1) You create a file model and put it in the Models folder. That model can even almost empty, like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Session;
use DB;
class Booking extends Model{
```

2) Then in the Controller you create an instance of that Model, like this

```
$theinstance = new Booking;
```

3) Then you use that object to have the values given, like this:

```
$theinstance->name = $name;
$theinstance->telephone = $telephone;
$theinstance->save();
```

That would be the way to save data.

Now, with regards to the update, at the Controller you can have something like this:

```
$photosslide = Property::returnPhotosSlide($id);  
      $propertydetails = Property::returnPropertyDetails($id);
      $alsointown = Property::returnAlsoInTown($id);
      return view('detailsproperty', compact('photosslide','propertydetails','alsointown'));
```

This sends the values from a Form into the Model

and once you are in the Model, just do an Update query.

Comment: You're really not answering the question, sorry but had to vote this down.

Comment: you need to calm down buddy, you're not scaring anyone, you're just embarrassing yourself. Admin get this guy out of here!

Comment: The web is full of comments critizing unfair, abusive and personal ill and bad faith attitudes of a profile of people who for the sake of annoying othes vote them down. Let me tell you, I have seen a beginner with 4 reputation trying to ask the best he could do. He was aggressively voted down. I felt for him and did my best to help him. I helped him on the way to his answer, because I know what it is like to start. It is cruel to vote people down when they are still trying to do their best and that is what people like you do and others do.

Comment: I voted it down because it's not helpful to the question..nothing personal.

Comment: The problem is that you are considering that insisting on following his wrong approach to the solution would be in line with the right answer. A helpful answer can be one that actually works even though it is a complete separate way from what he was doing. The answer I have given him is from the working code I have on my web and shows how to deal with the Model. His question was: How can I send in a model, when the values being passed are from a user form? and my answer was as it shows.